# Is Shooting the best NDSolve method for two point conditions, and how to improve its accuracy?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions

Hi I have a  two point conditions problem (controlled SIR epidemics via Pontryagin BVP), which is  supposed to depend heavily on initial conditions, which break the problem into several cases (choosing one case is the uncomprehensible part of my program in the beginning).  I realized that even my best `NDSolve` `Shooting` method may get  wrong  answers (for example for the initial values, see printout below); in fact, from the comments below it may be that  using  `NDSolve` in two-point problems  may not be ideal.

In light of the difficulties mentioned also in the answers, I am going to add two more aspects to the quest. The optimization problem also requires  to ``flatten the green i curve" (infections) by a state constraint i \leq iM,  which may be handled by adding `WhenEvent[i[t] > iM, i[t] -> iM-.0001]` to the equations.

```
    Clear["Global`*"]; \[Alpha] = 5/10; \[Rho] = 137/100; \[Gamma] = 
 1/18; R0 = 28/10; \[Beta] = \[Gamma] R0;
bl = 4 \[Beta]/(10); Rl = 
 bl/\[Gamma]; h = ((# - 1 - Log[#])/#) &; g = (1 - 1/#) &;
g0 = g[R0]; h0 = h[R0];
gs = g[Rl]; hs = h[Rl]; iM2 = (4 gs + hs)/5;(*CHOOSE iM*)iM = gs;
s0f = (Exp[# (1 - iM) - 1]/#) &;
s0 = N[s0f[Rl]] + .07; i0 = 1 - s0 // N;
tf = 80;
pw = Re[(#/\[Rho])^(1/(-1 + \[Rho]))] &;
arg = Min[\[Beta], 
    Max[\[Beta] - pw[#], bl]] &(*doesn't work with piecewise*);
upon[t_] := arg[i[t] s[t] (pi[t] - ps[t])];
sys = {odes, 
    bcs} = {{s'[t] == -u[t]*s[t]*i[t], 
     i'[t] == i[t] (u[t]*s[t] - \[Gamma]), 
     ps'[t] == u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]), 
     pi'[t] == u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]) - \[Alpha] + pi[t] \[Gamma], 
     WhenEvent[i[t] > iM, i[t] -> iM-.0001]}, {i[0] == i0, s[0] == s0, 
     ps[tf] == 0, pi[tf] == \[Alpha]/\[Gamma]}};
dvars = {i, s, ps, pi};
sol = NDSolve[sys /. u[t] -> upon[t], dvars, {t, 0, tf}, 
   Method -> "Shooting", WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
Print["Rl=", 
 Rl // N, " hard i_M inter= ", {h[Rl], g[Rl]} // 
  N, " s0=", s0, " >I=", 
 1/R0 // N, " i0=", (i /. First[sol])[0], "=", i0, " iM=", iM // N]
uop = Plot[{Evaluate[{(upon[t]/\[Beta]), bl/\[Beta], i[t], iM, 
      s[t](*,\[Psi][t]*)} /. sol]}, {t, 0, tf}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"control =upon[t]/\[Beta]", 
    "lower bound for control", "i[t]=infectious", 
    "iM=max allowable for infection", "s[t]=susceptibles"(*,
    "\[Psi][t] (determines control"*)}, 
  Epilog -> {Black, Dashed, Line[{{0, 1}, {tf, 1}}]}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Framed["Plot of control upon/\[Beta]"], 16, Blue, 
    Background -> Lighter[Yellow]], AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

The optimality is supposed to come from the choice
`upon[t_] := arg[i[t] s[t] (pi[t] - ps[t])]`
see https://elischolar.library.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1213&context=cowles-discussion-paper-series

The goal of the lowerbound `bl' is to pinpoint the optimal period for total confinement, when the control is a ``lower bang". A sharp transition to the lower bang is sure to happen when $\rho$ becomes 1, but seems difficult to get numerically.

Even with  bigger $\rho$, bad things happen: note that the computed i[0] in my example is twice the one specified by the initial condition.

The plots, assuming  tf is big enough,  are supposed to show  an increasing then decreasing i(infection).   Sometimes https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00318 there may be infectious with two optimal  peaks, and possibly several peaks for non-optimal arbitrary government policies might be possible.

Comment: Briefly: (1) There might be no solution. (2) If there is a solution, you need `"StartingInitialConditions"` that are good enough; problems in which there is little knowledge of what good starting points could be called "difficult." (3) `Method -> "FiniteElement"` is now an option for nonlinear BVPs (in V12.?); it can be used either to solve the system or get good starting points. (4) `ParametricNDSolve[]` can be used for greater control over shooting (one could use `NMinimize` on the norm of the residual of the boundary conditions instead of `FindRoot`). (5) There's the chasing method.

Comment: @florin  `NDSolve` is not right method for optimization problem. Please, have a look my answer to this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239572/ndsolve-to-automate-shooting-method-or-others-for-free-boundary-value-problem/239582#239582

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way that would work for ODE systems that do not develop singularities, assuming the desired BVP has a solution.
We use `NMinimize` to hunt down decent starting initial conditions.

```
sys = {odes, bcs} = {{s'[t] == -u[t]*s[t]*i[t], 
     i'[t] == i[t] (u[t]*s[t] - γ), 
     ps'[t] == u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]), 
     pi'[t] == u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]) - α + pi[t] γ},
    {i[0] == i0, s[0] == s0, ps[tf] == 0, pi[tf] == (α/γ)}};
dvars = {i, s, ps, pi};

params = {i1, s1, ps1, pi1};
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {odes, Through[dvars@0] == params} /. u[t] -> upon[t],
  dvars, {t, 0, tf}, params,
  Method -> {"Shooting", Method -> Automatic, 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> Thread[Through[dvars@0] == params]},
  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]

bcerr[i1_?NumericQ, s1_?NumericQ, ps1_?NumericQ, pi1_?NumericQ] := 
  Total[(
     bcs /. Equal -> Subtract /. 
      Thread[dvars -> psol @@ {i1, s1, ps1, pi1}]
     )^2];
{norm, icsNM} = 
 NMinimize[{bcerr @@ params , And @@ Thread[params > 0]},
  params,
  WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
  MaxIterations -> 10]
(*  {2.28422, {i1 -> 1.13849, s1 -> 0.000107863, ps1 -> 12.6763, pi1 -> 13.2513}}  *)

sol = NDSolve[
 sys /. u[t] -> upon[t],
 dvars, {t, 0, tf},
 Method -> {"Shooting", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", 
   "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    Thread[Through[dvars@0] == params /. icsNM]},
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
```

Comment: How we know that result of this code is numerical optimal solution of the  SIR epidemic model with time-dependent control? Probably we need some reference to compare.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I suppose you're referring to BVPs to possibly having multiple solutions and choosing one that optimizes some measure of utility. I don't know anything about "optimal" SIR solutions. What I did doesn't try to optimize anything, just find one solution to the BVP. (`NMinimize` is used to cast a broader net to try to locate a solution, it being less dependent on having a good starting position than `FindRoot`.)  The final solution is the result of the built-in `"Shooting"` method, which gives no error in this case and so should be as reliable as `NDSolve`.

Comment: Any way (+1) for the original solution. Just pay attention, it is not working for $\rho = 137/100$ and around. And I am not able to check how `NDSolve[]` accepts `u[t]`. There are no messages, but may be `NDSolve[]` just ignores this function.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks. It seems to be a "difficult" BVP. `NMinimize` struggles to minimize the norm of the residuals of the BVP in the given problem, and never could meet the precision goal IIRC. I limited the max iterations to `10` because more didn't help much and used a lot of time. I gave up on an automatic method that would solve for all parameters. I'm not surprised that adjustments would be necessary for different ranges of parameter values. Perhaps it is just too sensitive. I don't feel I have time for an in-depth analysis of it.

Comment: @AlexTrounev   thanks  for pointing out NDSolve may not be ideal method for BVP, and for your advice, which I'm studying now. For basics of UNCONTROLLED SIR, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model
The controlled  problem, giving rise to Pontryagin type problems is a recent research topic from last year -- see for example https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00318 and it has been tackled sometimes via the package https://www.bocop.org/download/  I am trying to do it with Mathematica

Comment: @Michael E2. The nature of the results is quite sensitive to the initial values,  so I  am  not sure if searching  for good initial conditions is allowed here. I have reformulated the question and gave a new example, trying to be more precise on the nature of the problem.

Comment: @florin It could be good to discuss examples from section 7 of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.00318.pdf

Comment: @Alex Trounev it would be a pleasure, both for me and probably also for the author Lorenzo, with which I'm just collaborating these days on some sequels. We should probably switch to emails

Comment: @florin We can start new topic on this forum with case $J_{QQ}$ to compare Bocop simulation with Mathematica.

Comment: @Alex Trounev Great! I never used the forum though, please lead the way :)

Comment: @florin It is very good!  Could you start a new topic with the case  $J_{QQ}$?

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of optimization problem, and it can be solved with `NMinimize[]` using colocation method and Haar wavelets as follows.
Define parameters (we change parameter $\rho$ to some reliable value)

```
tf = 80; \[Alpha] = 5/10; \[Rho] = 
 137/100; \[Gamma] = 1/18; R0 = 
 28/10; \[Beta] = \[Gamma] \
R0;
    bl = 4 \[Beta]/(10); Rl = 
 bl/\[Gamma]; H = ((# - 1 - Log[#])/#) &; g = (1 - 1/#) &;
g0 = g[R0]; h0 = H[R0];
gs = g[Rl]; hs = H[Rl]; iM2 = (gs + hs)/2;
iM = iM2;
    s0f = (Exp[# (1 - iM) - 1]/#) &;
    s0 = N[s0f[Rl]] + .05;
Print["Rl=",
      Rl // N, " hard i_M inter= ", {H[Rl], g[Rl]} // 
      N, " s0=", s0, " >I=", 1/R0 // N, " i0=", i0 = 1 - s0 // N, " iM=", 
     iM // N]
```

Define collocation points, wavelets, functions and derivatives

```
A = 0; B = 1; J = 4; M = 2^J; dx = (B - A)/(2*M); 
  h1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, A <= x <= B}, {0, True}}]; 
  p1[x_, n_] := (1/n!)*(x - A)^n; 
h[x_, k_, m_] := Piecewise[{{1, Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, Less, 
      (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, {-1, Inequality[(1 + 2*k)/(2*m), LessEqual, x, Less, 
      (1 + k)/m]}}, 0]
p[x_, k_, m_, n_] := Piecewise[{{0, x < k/m}, {(-(k/m) + x)^n/n!, 
     Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, Less, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, 
    {((-(k/m) + x)^n - 2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, 
     (1 + 2*k)/(2*m) <= x <= (1 + k)/m}, 
    {((-(k/m) + x)^n + (-((1 + k)/m) + x)^n - 2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, 
     x > (1 + k)/m}}, 0]
xl = Table[A + l*dx, {l, 0, 2*M}]; xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, 
    {l, 2, 2*M + 1}]; 
iH1[x_] := Sum[aiH[i, j]*h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    a0*h1[x]; 
iH0[x_] := Sum[aiH[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 1], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    a0*p1[x, 1] + a1; 
sH1[x_] := Sum[asH[i, j]*h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    b0*h1[x]; 
sH0[x_] := Sum[asH[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 1], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    b0*p1[x, 1] + b1; 
psH1[x_] := Sum[apsH[i, j]*h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    c0*h1[x]; 
psH0[x_] := Sum[apsH[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 1], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    c0*p1[x, 1] + c1; 
piH1[x_] := Sum[apiH[i, j]*h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    d0*h1[x]; 
piH0[x_] := Sum[apiH[i, j]*p[x, i, 2^j, 1], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
    d0*p1[x, 1] + d1;
```

Define variables, function `u[t]`, constrains and equations

```
var = Flatten[
  Table[{aiH[i, j], asH[i, j], apiH[i, j], apsH[i, j]}, {j, 0, J, 
    1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]; varX = 
 Join[{a0, a1, b0, b1, c0, c1, d0, d1}, var];
pw[x_] := Re[(x/\[Rho])^(1/(-1 + \[Rho]))];
arg[x_] := Min[\[Beta], Max[\[Beta] - pw[x], bl]];
u[t_] := arg[iH0[t] sH0[t] (piH0[t] - psH0[t])];
cons0 = {iH0[0] - i0 == 0, sH0[0] - s0 == 0, psH0[1] == 0, 
   piH0[1] - (\[Alpha]/\[Gamma]) == 0}; 
cons1 = Flatten[
   Table[{iH0[t] >= 0, sH0[t] >= 0, piH0[t] >= 0, psH0[t] >= 0}, {t, 
     xcol}]];
cons = Join[cons0, cons1];

eqn = {-s'[t]/tf - u[t]*s[t]*i[t], -i'[t]/tf + 
     i[t] (u[t]*s[t] - \[Gamma]), -ps'[t]/tf + 
     u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]), -pi'[t]/tf + 
     u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]) - \[Alpha] + pi[t] \[Gamma]} /. {i -> 
     iH0, i' -> iH1, s -> sH0, s' -> sH1, ps -> psH0, ps' -> psH1, 
    pi -> piH0, pi' -> piH1};
eq =  Flatten[Table[eqn, {t, xcol}]];
```

Solve minimization problem

```
solM = NMinimize[{Norm[eq], cons}, varX]

(*{0.0104057, {a0 -> 0.0954815, a1 -> 0.00508882, b0 -> -0.375913, 
  b1 -> 0.994911, c0 -> -3.90017, c1 -> 3.90017, d0 -> -0.677472, 
  d1 -> 9.67747, aiH[0, 0] -> 0.0660761, asH[0, 0] -> -0.063544, 
  apiH[0, 0] -> 1.00814, apsH[0, 0] -> 0.405986, 
  aiH[0, 1] -> 0.188154, asH[0, 1] -> 0.0376435, 
  apiH[0, 1] -> 0.487586, apsH[0, 1] -> 0.593654, 
  aiH[1, 1] -> 0.0444829, asH[1, 1] -> -0.0189795, 
  apiH[1, 1] -> 1.0024, apsH[1, 1] -> 0.150677, aiH[0, 2] -> 0.06544, 
  asH[0, 2] -> 0.11632, apiH[0, 2] -> 0.725894, apsH[0, 2] -> 0.87757,
   aiH[1, 2] -> -0.0234203, asH[1, 2] -> -0.00566019, 
  apiH[1, 2] -> 0.338734, apsH[1, 2] -> 0.30369, 
  aiH[2, 2] -> 0.0252932, asH[2, 2] -> -0.0104613, 
  apiH[2, 2] -> 0.258855, apsH[2, 2] -> 0.0964121, 
  aiH[3, 2] -> -0.0265804, asH[3, 2] -> -0.00918152, 
  apiH[3, 2] -> 0.756419, apsH[3, 2] -> 0.0304156, 
  aiH[0, 3] -> -0.0745347, asH[0, 3] -> 0.137549, 
  apiH[0, 3] -> 0.650927, apsH[0, 3] -> 0.875131, 
  aiH[1, 3] -> 0.170202, asH[1, 3] -> -0.0411005, 
  apiH[1, 3] -> -0.257863, apsH[1, 3] -> -0.248828, 
  aiH[2, 3] -> -0.0160979, asH[2, 3] -> 0.00409634, 
  apiH[2, 3] -> 0.190301, apsH[2, 3] -> 0.219103, 
  aiH[3, 3] -> -0.0198636, asH[3, 3] -> -0.0159907, 
  apiH[3, 3] -> 0.172247, apsH[3, 3] -> 0.103688, 
  aiH[4, 3] -> 0.0401597, asH[4, 3] -> -0.0287653, 
  apiH[4, 3] -> -0.169186, apsH[4, 3] -> -0.225655, 
  aiH[5, 3] -> 0.0146636, asH[5, 3] -> 0.00353028, 
  apiH[5, 3] -> 0.260637, apsH[5, 3] -> 0.124237, 
  aiH[6, 3] -> 0.000467526, asH[6, 3] -> -0.00932397, 
  apiH[6, 3] -> 0.24602, apsH[6, 3] -> -0.0247289, 
  aiH[7, 3] -> 0.0109868, asH[7, 3] -> 0.00531618, 
  apiH[7, 3] -> 0.533452, apsH[7, 3] -> 0.0562497, 
  aiH[0, 4] -> -0.0161501, asH[0, 4] -> 0.0650699, 
  apiH[0, 4] -> 0.2376, apsH[0, 4] -> 0.391809, 
  aiH[1, 4] -> -0.0423136, asH[1, 4] -> 0.0705367, 
  apiH[1, 4] -> 0.412222, apsH[1, 4] -> 0.478024, 
  aiH[2, 4] -> 0.0484061, asH[2, 4] -> -0.0108476, 
  apiH[2, 4] -> -0.00221506, apsH[2, 4] -> -0.00930998, 
  aiH[3, 4] -> 0.0791673, asH[3, 4] -> -0.0115428, 
  apiH[3, 4] -> -0.11338, apsH[3, 4] -> -0.0820615, 
  aiH[4, 4] -> 0.0275533, asH[4, 4] -> 0.0115671, 
  apiH[4, 4] -> 0.102044, apsH[4, 4] -> 0.128047, 
  aiH[5, 4] -> -0.0124024, asH[5, 4] -> -0.00230487, 
  apiH[5, 4] -> 0.0969294, apsH[5, 4] -> 0.0958279, 
  aiH[6, 4] -> -0.00120586, asH[6, 4] -> -0.00779982, 
  apiH[6, 4] -> 0.0704392, apsH[6, 4] -> 0.0433793, 
  aiH[7, 4] -> -0.0307616, asH[7, 4] -> -0.0103363, 
  apiH[7, 4] -> 0.10174, apsH[7, 4] -> 0.0517215, 
  aiH[8, 4] -> -0.000430565, asH[8, 4] -> -0.0314585, 
  apiH[8, 4] -> -0.153533, apsH[8, 4] -> -0.199178, 
  aiH[9, 4] -> 0.00501252, asH[9, 4] -> 0.00718202, 
  apiH[9, 4] -> 0.0937051, apsH[9, 4] -> 0.0750744, 
  aiH[10, 4] -> -0.00331805, asH[10, 4] -> 0.00282372, 
  apiH[10, 4] -> 0.132389, apsH[10, 4] -> 0.0815513, 
  aiH[11, 4] -> 0.020478, asH[11, 4] -> -0.000615826, 
  apiH[11, 4] -> 0.132089, apsH[11, 4] -> 0.0428073, 
  aiH[12, 4] -> 0.0103351, asH[12, 4] -> -0.00509096, 
  apiH[12, 4] -> 0.104502, apsH[12, 4] -> -0.0156213, 
  aiH[13, 4] -> -0.0103834, asH[13, 4] -> -0.0039744, 
  apiH[13, 4] -> 0.135814, apsH[13, 4] -> -0.0174982, 
  aiH[14, 4] -> -0.0082928, asH[14, 4] -> 0.00002658, 
  apiH[14, 4] -> 0.219744, apsH[14, 4] -> 0.0166508, 
  aiH[15, 4] -> 0.0374625, asH[15, 4] -> 0.0114181, 
  apiH[15, 4] -> 0.311253, apsH[15, 4] -> 0.0345916}}*)
```

Plot numerical solution and check errors for every colocation point

```
{Plot[
  Evaluate[{iH0[t/tf], sH0[t/tf], psH0[t/tf], piH0[t/tf]} /. 
    solM[[2]]], {t, 0, tf}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"i, NMinimize", "s, NMinimize", "ps, NMinimize", 
    "pi, NMinimize"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],


Plot[Evaluate[{iH0[t/tf], sH0[t/tf]} /. solF], {t, 0, tf}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"i, FindRoot", "s, FindRoot"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotPoints -> 200]}
```

[image: Figure 1]
Unfortunately there is no any method to compare with. Also maximal error is of $3\times 10^{-3}$ and mean error is of $8\times10^{-5}$, and it corresponds to $(\Delta x)^2=1/32^2$, nevertheless we need some reference data. For this we run `FindRoot[]` with initial point at `solM` as

```
solF = FindRoot[Join[Table[eq[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eq]}], cons0], 
   Table[{varX[[i]], varX[[i]] /. solM[[2]]}, {i, Length[varX]}], 
   MaxIterations -> 1000];
```

Finally we plot 2 solutions and check improvement

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[{iH0[t/tf], sH0[t/tf]} /. solF], {t, 0, tf}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"i, FindRoot", "s, FindRoot"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotPoints -> 200], Plot[Evaluate[{iH0[t/tf], sH0[t/tf]} /. solM[[2]]], {t, 0, tf}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"i, NMinimize", "s, NMinimize"}] ]
```

[image: Figure 2]

```
Show[Plot[Evaluate[{piH0[t/tf], psH0[t/tf]} /. solF], {t, 0, tf}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"pi, FindRoot", "ps, FindRoot"}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotPoints -> 200], 
 Plot[Evaluate[{piH0[t/tf], psH0[t/tf]} /. solM[[2]]], {t, 0, tf}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"pi, NMinimize", "ps, NMinimize"}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: (+1) Perhaps you meant to format the `Plot` code at the end?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you! Next step is to use `FindRoot[]` with  initial point at `solM`.