# Solving non-linear BVP with NDSolve and shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I'm trying to solve a set of non linear DAE with global constraint
$$k(x) \left(\frac{1}{40} \omega ^4 n(x)^2+\frac{2}{3}\right)-L \lambda (x)-\frac{2}{3}=0,\ \ n(x) \left(\frac{1}{40} \omega ^4 k(x)^2+\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{9} \left(6-t \omega ^2 n''(x)\right)=0$$
$$2 \pi -\int_0^L k(x) \, dx=0$$
In order to get a set of ODE's I denoted $y(x)=n'(x)$ and replaced the constrain with another function $z'(x)=k(x)$ s.t. $z(0)=0$ and $z(2\pi)=L$ so the equivalent set of equations are
$$k'(x) \left(\frac{1}{40} \omega ^4 n(x)^2+\frac{2}{3}\right)+k(x) \frac{1}{20} \omega ^4 n(x)y(x)=0$$
$$n(x) \left(\frac{1}{40} \omega ^4 k(x)^2+\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{9} \left(6-t \omega ^2 y'(x)\right)=0$$
$$y(x)=n'(x)$$
$$z'(x)=k(x)$$
Where I have assumed $\lambda$ is constant.

I know that $k(x)$ and $n(x)$ are periodic function with period L and that the constant solution $k=2\pi/L$ satisfies the eq and constrain.

As it is a BVP, I have tried to solve it with shooting method, but I failed to get periodic solution in $n$ although I have demanded it.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
\[Nu] = 0;

h[k_, n_] := \[Omega]^4/80 (k n)^2 +   1/3 (2 (1 - \[Nu]) (\[Omega]^2 t/
     12 (D[n, x])^2 + (1 - k) (1 + n)) + (n + k)^2)
L[k_, n_, \[Lambda]_] :=  h[k, n] - \[Lambda] ( Integrate[k, {x, 0, L}] - 2 \[Pi])
nini[w_, k_] := -( 2/3) ((1 - \[Nu]) (1 - k) + k) ((w^4/40) k^2  + 
 2/3)^-1 // FullSimplify
L=10;
t=0.001;
EL = EulerEquations[L[k[x], n[x], \[Lambda][x]], {k[x], n[x]}, x]

{-(2/3) + k[x] (2/3 + 1/40 \[Omega]^4 n[x]^2) - L \[Lambda][x] == 0, (2/3 + 1/40 \[Omega]^4 [x]^2) n[x] + 1/9 (6 - t \[Omega]^2 (n^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]) == 0}

Table[Table[Plot[Evaluate[{k[x], n[x], y[x], z[x]} /. 
 NDSolve[{k'[x] == -k[x] (1/40) \[Omega]^4 n[x] y[
      x] ((1/40) \[Omega]^4 (n[x])^2 + 2/3)^-1 , 
   y'[x] == (1/(t \[Omega]^2)) (9 n[x] ((1/40) \[Omega]^4 (k[x])^2 + 2/3) - 6), 
   n'[x] == y[x], z'[x] == k[x], z[0] == 0, z[L] == 2 \[Pi], 
   n[0] == n[L ], k[0] == k[L ]}, {k, n, y, z}, {x, 0, L}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0,k[0] == 2 \[Pi]/L - i , n[0] == nini[\[Omega], 2 \[Pi]/L - i]}}]], {x, 0, L},  PlotLegends -> {"k", "n", "y", "z"},PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotLabel ->"\[Omega] = " <> ToString@\[Omega] "  i= " <> ToString@i],{i, -1, 1, 0.2}], {\[Omega], {0.1,25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.5, 3, 5, 10}}]
```

$\omega$ is a parameter and $i$ is used for guessing the initial value of $k(0)$ (Where I have guessed it should be near $2\pi /L$)

[image]

Moreover, the solution of $z$ doesn't obey $z(0)=0$

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have assumed $\lambda$ is constant

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please edit your question to include that `λ`  is constant.

Comment: Your code doesn't currently run because you define the Lagrangian (?) as `L[k,n,lambda]` and then set `L = 10` two lines below it.

Comment: Also, you should include `Needs["VariationalMethods\`"]` at the start of your code;  `EulerEquations` is not defined by default in Mathematica.  In addition, `\[Omega]` and `\[Nu]` are not defined.

Comment: I rolled back an edit because the code was not copyable anymore (``\`` and ``[`` where swapped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this BVP as some kind of optimization problem with `NMinimize`, and then we can improve solution with using Newton's iterative method with `FindRoot`. Note, same algorithm has been implemented in my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239976/is-shooting-the-best-ndsolve-method-for-two-point-conditions-and-how-to-improve/240204#240204). We define $n1=n',k1=k', z1=z',y1=y',omega=\omega$, and use `n0[x]` instead of `n[x]` since `n` is used as some integer in the code below. To make efficient FDM algorithm we use Bernoulli wavelets as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

L = 10;
t = 10^-3; omega = 1; eq = {-k1[x]/L - 
   k[x] (1/40) omega^4 n0[x] y[
     x] ((1/40) omega^4 (n0[x])^2 + 2/3)^(-1), -y1[x]/
    L + (1/(t omega^2)) (9 n0[x] ((1/40) omega^4 (k[x])^2 + 2/3) - 6),
   n1[x]/L - y[x], z1[x]/L - k[x]}; con = {z[0] == 0, z[1] == 2 Pi, 
  n0[0] == n0[1], k[0] == k[1]};

n = 4;
M = Sum[1, {j, 0, n, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 1;
dx = 1/M; xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, M}]; tcol = 
 xcol = Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, M + 1}]; 
psi1[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[2, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi2[x_] := Piecewise[{{BernoulliB[1, x], 0 <= x < 1}, {0, True}}];
psi1jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi1[j*x - k];
psi2jk[x_, j_, k_] := psi2[j*x - k];
psijk = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, (psi1jk[x,
        j, k] + psi2jk[x, j, k])/2];
psijk1 = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, 
   Piecewise[{{(-k + k^2)/(2*j), 
      j > 0 && k == 0 && 
       1/j - x < 0}, {(1/6)*(-x + 3*k^2*x - 3*j*k*x^2 + j^2*x^3), 
      j > 0 && k == 0 && x > 0 && 
       1/j - x >= 
        0}, {(k - k^3 - j*x + 3*j*k^2*x - 3*j^2*k*x^2 + j^3*x^3)/(6*
         j), j > 0 && k > 0 && k/j - x < 0 && 1/j + k/j - x >= 0}}, 
    0]];
Psi[x_] := 
  Join[{1}, 
   Flatten[Table[psijk[x, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
int1[x_] := 
  Join[{x}, 
   Flatten[Table[
     psijk1[x, 2^j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
var1 = Join[{a0}, 
  Flatten[Table[a[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var2 = 
 Join[{b0}, 
  Flatten[Table[b[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var3 = 
 Join[{c0}, 
  Flatten[Table[c[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]]; var4 = 
 Join[{d0}, Flatten[Table[d[j, k], {j, 0, n, 1}, {k, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]]];
z1[t_] := var3 . Psi[t]; z[t_] := var3 . int1[t] + c1;
y1[t_] := var1 . Psi[t]; y[t_] := var1 . int1[t] + a1; 
k1[t_] := var2 . Psi[t]; k[t_] := var2 . int1[t] + b1;
n1[t_] := var4 . Psi[t]; n0[t_] := var4 . int1[t] + d1;
```

Finally we define variables and system of algebraic equations to minimize

```
varM = Join[{a1, b1, c1, d1}, var1, var2, var3, var4]; eqM = 
 Flatten[Table[eq /. x -> xcol[[j]] // Quiet, {j, M}]];

sol = NMinimize[{Norm[eqM], con}, varM]
```

Visualization

```
{Plot[n0[t/L] /. sol[[2]], {t, 0, L}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "n"], 
 Plot[k[t/L] /. sol[[2]], {t, 0, L}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "k"],
  Plot[z[t/L] /. sol[[2]], {t, 0, L}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotLabel -> "z"], 
 Plot[y[t/L] /. sol[[2]], {t, 0, L}, Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> "y"]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Unfortunately this solution is not so precise, but we can improve it as follows

```
sol1 = FindRoot[Join[Table[eqM[[j]] == 0, {j, Length[eqM]}], con], 
  Table[{varM[[i]], varM[[i]] /. sol[[2]]}, {i, Length[varM]}]]
```

Visualization
[image: Figure 2]